# Fill form in Android using textView and editText aligned

Tags: java, android, forms

I'm trying to create an activity where the user has a text and some editText to fill the details they want. I've attached an image but the text will be far longer. Something like an invoice to fill or an application form. As well the fields will be many too.

[image]

**Here is the xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="dev.long1.smartprintthermalprinter.FillForm"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_fill_form">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTitleFillForm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Fill form"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textHintFillForm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textTitleFillForm"
                android:text="Fill the form with desired content."
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFormNameFillForm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textHintFillForm"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="file address.tpf"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFillForm"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="My name is"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:hint="name"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="and I have"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:hint="age"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="years."
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText2" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want basically?

Comment: Something like a form. Ex an invoice. In the invoice there is some predefined text and fields for the user to fill, like name, address, phone.

Comment: How will the app handle dynamic form fields...especially from unknown forms?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I'm not very advanced just learning.